# Conditionally replace values from multiple columns with values from one column

Tags: r, replace, data.table

My aim is to replace values from multiple columns by values in a column `b_Y_1`, provided they are not missing. If there is a missing value in a column `b_Y_1` for the corresponding line, it remains unchanged. My problem is that I do not know how to write "remains unchanged" for more columns at once.

I use `data.table` package.

```
data[ ,c("a_.Y3_1","a_.Y3_2","a_.Y3_3","a_Y1_1","a_Y1_2","a_Y1_3") := ifelse(!is.na(data$b_Y_1), data$b_Y_1,????)]
```

Comment: If I'm understanding the logic correctly, you want to replace multiple column values with the value from `b_Y_1` as long as `b_Y_1` is not `NA`. If `b_Y_1` is `NA` then no change. And this is done on a row-by-row basis. Is that correct?

Comment: You could try something like this: `dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(!is.na(b_Y_1), b_Y_1, x)), .SDcols = c("a_.Y3_1","a_.Y3_2","a_.Y3_3","a_Y1_1","a_Y1_2","a_Y1_3")]`